# updating djangocms database entry via script not working with cronjob

Tags: python, django-models, ckeditor, cron, django-cms

I have a python script which automatically updates a database entry of the `djangocms_text_ckeditor_text` table. I'm using djangocms 3 on debian wheezy. When running this script from the bash with `trutty:~$ ./update.py` it works and the database entry gets updated. However, when running the same script with a cronjob (specified in `crontab -e -u trutty`), the entry does not get updated although the script runs.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/home/trutty/v/bin/python
...
from django import settings
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.models import Text
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
...
c = CMSPlugin.objects.filter(placeholder_id=8, parent_id__isnull=True)
if c:
    t = Text.objects.get(pk=c.first().id)
    t.body = ...
    t.save()
    ...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what's your cronjob line in your cron file? It seems your cron job is not running.

Comment: the line in the crontab is `0 5 * * 1 /home/update.py > /home/log/update.log 2>&1` for running the script on mondays at 5 min after midnight. I can assure that the script is running because the log files' content gets written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now get the page object and save it right after `t.save()`.

```
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
...
p = Page.objects,get(...)
...
t.save()
p.save()
```